# return the field I received on serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I receive the request like:
post suggestion/

```
{
    "suggestions": [{
        "description": "Good One!!",
        "integration_type": "External",
    }]
}
```

I want to return this:

```
[
  {
    "url": "http://0.0.0.0:8000/suggestion/12",
    "id": 12,
    "date_created": "2016-07-08T11:40:01.582843Z",
    "name": "Coffee!!",
"integration_type": "External",
  }
]
```

In my model I have the "integration_type", but it doesn't return anything. It doesn't even appear.

I have like this:

```
integration_type = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
```

I need make sure that "integration_type" is on the request, and I want also return it.

Can someone help  a noobie? Thanks in advice

Comment: For a workaround, you can assign it to a variable, create a context or your json data and return the Response from the view.

Comment: if you want to have `integration_type` in the response, remove `write_only=True`